# Qt+boost+winsock2. Запускается, вылетает: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.

Tags: asio, windows, boost, qt, winsock

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Решал? winsock требуется при использовании boost::asio. Содержимое pro:

```
win32:LIBS += libws2_32

LIBS += -LC:/boost/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib \
            libboost_serialization-mgw48-1_54.dll \
            libboost_system-mgw48-1_54.dll \
            libboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_54.dll

LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib \
            libopencv_core246.dll \
            libopencv_highgui246.dll
```

вылетает до вызова main. Ошибка происходит в модуле libstdc++-6.dll

Comment: Можешь привести текст ошибки, желательно с кодом?

Comment: Код исключения c0000005. Пишет The program has unexpectedly finished.
filename.exe exited with code -1073741819

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант: попробовать прилинковать библиотеки через настройки проекта или положить в папку проекта или папку с исполняемым файлом, в зависимости от среды. 
Усли есть возможность, посмотреть видны ли исполняемому файлу библиотеки и какие библиотеки используются дальше. Это позволяет сделать http://wincmd.ru/plugring/peviewer.html модуль TotalCommander или некоторые подобные приложения.